# SAP HCP Neo logging configuration customizing

Tags: sap-cloud-platform

Does anyone know whether it is possible to customize logging for applications which are deployed on SAP HCP Neo Env. What exactly I need is either modifying of pattern layout or adding of new columns

[image]

For example, the picture above shows that we have several columns which are empty, I would like either to reuse them or to add my own columns. I have tried everything for now, but nothing helps me to get my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logging on NEO is currently not customizable.  Technically it's possible to use the MDC to provide custom columns, but with the current config, they will not be printed to the log file -> you'll have to open a feature/improvement request for that.